# Select checkbox - > click button - > update table values

Tags: jquery-plugins

initially values under **reattempt column** will be blank . Once we select checkboxes of some rows and click on button **reattempt** , i want to update the values of `column reattempt` to reattempt.

[image]

**html**

```
<button id="reattempt">reattempt</button>

<tr> 
    <th class="table-header">Reattempt</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td id="<?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["tracking_id"];?>reattempt">
        <?php echo $orderrecords[$k]["reattempt"]; ?>       
    </td>
</tr>
```

**script**

```
$('#reattempt').click(function() {
  var selected = [];
  $('.assigneeid-order:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).val());
    $('.assigneeid-order').prop('checked', false);
  });

  var jsonString = JSON.stringify(selected);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'reattempt.php',
    data: { data: jsonString },
    success: function(response) {
      response = $.parseJSON(response);

      $.each(response, function(index, val) {
        $('#' + index + '').html(val);
        $('#' + index + 'reattempt').html(val.reattempt);
      });
    }
  });
});
```

**reattempt.php**

```
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

foreach($data as $id)
{ 
    $orderid = $id; 
    $reattempt='';

    $sqlecom = "UPDATE do_order set reattempt = '$reattempt' where tracking_id=".$orderid;
    $db_handleecom = new DBController(); 
    $resultecom = $db_handleecom->executeUpdate($sqlecom); 

    $response[$orderid] = [ 'reattempt' => $reattempt ];
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

**Result**

Values not updating , below is response :

[image]

Comment: dont you have to include something to be able to use your db class?

Comment: @Breezer sorry, i am beginner in coding, can you please tell me what i need ?

Comment: in `reattempt.php` you need to include your database class, `DBController` is not a built in function/class

Comment: @Breezer yes , i included that in top of the file, sorry but did't mentioned in question  : `require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();`

Comment: And how does your class handle errors? You should try to get them shown in some matter to find out if there is any errors updating the table

Comment: @Breezer i also included these code in top of the file , i didt saw any error : `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL & ~MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166369/discussion-between-vickey-colors-and-breezer).

Comment: it probably because your class catches the error in some variable

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Thanks for suggestion, i will try to use Prepared statements.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting all of your checkboxes to unchecked with `$('.assigneeid-order').prop('checked', false);`, please edit with `$(this).prop('checked', false);` which will point to the current checkbox in the loop. Also, update your html with missing TDs

Nothing in your code is updating because in your php file, you are setting `$reattempt='';` and without any further changes, you are returning it as empty.. So, you can't expect other than an empty value..